# Finding the index of the element with class in native Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, indexing

Is there a way to get the index of class name (I.e. the third element with the class "className" would be 3 without using jQ?

I don't know jQ, and I don't have time to learn it right now, and I don't want to include code into my code that I don't understand at least some.

Thanks.

BTW, I've used jQ instead of spelling it out so those results can be filtered out in Google should somebody have the same question. If I spelled it out, and somebody used the NOT operator in Google, this one would also disappear.

Comment: The is the index() method in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Can you post a sample html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to find the index of a child node in parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656921/fastest-way-to-find-the-index-of-a-child-node-in-parent)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
   // your index is inside here
}
```

`el[i]` is the element in the current iteration, `i` is the index

> (I.e. the third element with the class "className" would be 3)

```
if (i == 3)
return el[i]
```

---

JsFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MYspu/1/).

Comment: +1 for non-jQ answer as asked. I'd prefer to use `document.querySelectorAll`, but eh.

Comment: I've prepared a different one. Still, same principle applies.

Comment: In Response To:  Ayman Safadi

The demo you provide unfortunately doesn't apply to the question and with it you have added an additional value in simply retrieving the node's current index. To others please disregard as:

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('elementClass'); var aValue = a[0]; Is the same as simply saying document.getElementsByClassName('elementClass')[0]

Answer (score 20):

You could do something like:

```
// the element you're looking for
var target = document.getElementById("an-element");

// the collection you're looking in
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".yourclass");

var index = [].indexOf.call(nodes, target);
```

See: [Array's indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
If you have already a proper array as `nodes` instead of a NodeList, you can just do `nodes.indexOf(target)`.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I remember indexOf not being supported in older browsers like IE8. Still, I don't know if this limitation applied to nodes collections AND arrays or only arrays.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the link as well. If older browsers are a concern, I honestly think that the OP have bigger problem than that in DOM manipulation, and should use jQuery. However, in the link, there is also a shim – personally nowadays I would use a ES5 shim always for older browsers. Also, if the browser support `querySelectorAll`, it should support `indexOf` too, so I do not see a big issue here. Again, it depends if he wants target modern browsers or not. In the second scenario, I will suggest jQuery, or at least ES5 shim.

Comment: Array.prototype.indexOf.call(nodes, target); This achieves the same, but looks a bit more professional

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), it returns a list of elements with the specified classes.

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test")
element = elements[2] //get the 3rd element
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

these work as of es6:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.elements')).indexOf(anElement)
```

or

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.elements')].indexOf(anElement)
```