# Finding the index of the first array element that contains a particular CSS class using native javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a few buttons on a page who all share the `.btn` class, and only one at any particular time has another class, `.selected`, which changes.

In my javascript I've declared an array of elements with the `.btn` class:

`var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");`

I'd like to get the index of the first (and in this case, only) occurrence of the element that also has the `.selected` class.

So far as I can tell, *without using jQ*, I should be able to find the index by using `findIndex()`, which requires a testing function. I can't seem to write that function though, because I am unsure how to test if an element from an array contains a particular class, without having a variable for the individual element.

[Finding the index of the element with class in native Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784453/finding-the-index-of-the-element-with-class-in-native-javascript) -- This question from Nov '16 seems to ask nearly the same question but the top answer suggests using `document.getElementByClass()` which returns an array, not an index.

[Test if an element contains a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class) -- Here the answer appears to work for testing individual elements, but if I'm trying to iterate through an array without a loop (i.e. using something like `findIndex()`), I don't have a `var` to use the `element.contains` notation.

So more or less I'm trying to pass the index into another function:

`someFunc(btn.findIndex(element.classList.contains("selected"));`, but struggling to determine how to use the `indexOf()` method to find the location.

I'm obviously new to JS, so any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use document.querySelector('.btn.selected')

Comment: ah, instead of using the index, just grab the element using both classes.. brilliant! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Document#querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get a single reference, and use as you're query `.btn.selected`, and if there are any other elements with `.selected`, or just `.selected` if it can be attached only to `.btn`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".btn.selected"));
console.log(document.querySelector(".selected"));

/** you can use the reference to change the button styling **/
document.querySelector(".selected").style.background = "green";

/** you can assign it to a variable to use multiple times **/
var selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
selected.style.border = "1px solid red";
selected.style.color = "white";
```

```html
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn selected">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
<button class="btn">5</button>
```

If we really do want the index, use [Document#querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a list of btns, and use [Array#findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the element that is equal to the one you got using Document#querySelector.

Since the list of nodes is not a true array, we need to convert it to an array (using Array#from for example), or use [Function#call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to invoke findIndex on it.

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var selected = document.querySelector(".selected");

var index = [].findIndex.call(btns, function(btn) {
  return btn === selected;
});

console.log(index);
```

```html
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn selected">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
<button class="btn">5</button>
```

Comment: Say I want to single out the one button to change its background color for instance. Can I use `document.querySelector(".btn.selected).backgroundColor = "green";`? or does it need a `var`?

Comment: You can use the reference you get directly (see modified 1st example). If you want to use it multiple times, it's better to assign it to a variable.